# what are possible indications that the spark plugs of my motorcycle need replacing?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, sparkplugs, cbr929rr

Is there a way to find out, without taking the motorcycle to a garage, that the spark plugs need changing?

In other words, if one or all of the sparking plugs of my motorcycle are worn out or need a change, how does that interfere in the normal behaviour of my bike?

this bike in scpefic is a 1998 Honda CBR 918RR Fireblade

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would be helpful to know the year/make/model/engine of the bike in question.

Comment: As far as physical inspection goes, usually, plugs are not very hard to gain access to and are removable with minimal tools. However, knowing the info about your bike would help.

Comment: What makes you think they need changing? In my experience plugs need far less maintenance and replacement than they get; my Yamaha FJ has had the same set of plugs for at least 15 years.

Comment: If the bike is running poorly, any number of issues could cause it. The only way I know of to check the spark plugs is to simply remove them and look at them. If the center or side electrodes are worn down and the gap is larger than it should be, then you should probably replace them, or at least re-gap them. Also inspect the ceramic for cracks which could leak spark.